# Pushing Items to an Object Within an Array in my Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

In my Angular2 app I am trying to figure out how to push a new object into an array that contains objects with three properties - when I only want to push one of those three properties. Take this array for instance:

```
locations = [
  { city: 'Los Angelas', zipcode: '90001', coordinates: 2321 },
  { city: 'New York', zipcode: '10001', coordinates: 3432 },
];
```

Here I want to ONLY push new zipcodes - not city names or coordinates. So, I'm assuming it would look like this after pushing a new object:

```
locations = [
  { city: 'Los Angelas', zipcode: '90001', coordinates: 2321 },
  { city: 'New York', zipcode: '10001', coordinates: 3432 },
  { zipcode: 20001 }
];
```

How would I handle this? Can I do this? Or would I need to pass null values for the other two properties?

Comment: can you please share  a sample array with expected output?

Comment: locations.push({zipCode:'any value'}) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean for an object that already exists? In that case,

```
let index = locations.findIndex(element => element.city === city)
locations[index].zipcode = newZipCode
```

Array.findIndex is not fully supported yet, so you might have to polyfill it, or you could use the method from lodash.

**EDIT**: Per my comment, this should work just fine now that I know what you're looking for:

```
locations.push({ zipcode: newZipCode })
```

Comment: No, I mean a new object (but that has just the one property - zipcode.

Comment: Then why can't you just use locations.push({ zipcode: newZipCode })

Comment: This is what I have for an array of objects that contains just one property:
  addZipcode(event) {
    this.zipcodes.push({ postalCode: this.newZipcode });
    this.newZipCode = '';
    this.addZipInput = false;
    event.preventDefault();
  }

Comment: Is it not more complicated when the objects in the array have multiple properties? Maybe I'm overthinking this?

Comment: It's not. You can simply use push. All of the objects in the array do not have to match their properties.

Comment: Yes, as I think about it, I realize you're right. An array can contain any combination of objects. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! It's easy to overthink things sometimes. :)

Comment: @Muirik Please mark the answer correct if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
locations = [
  { city: 'Los Angelas', zipcode: '90001', coordinates: 2321 },
  { city: 'New York', zipcode: '10001', coordinates: 3432 },
];

var tempObject = {
   zipcode : '10000'
}
locations.push(tempObject);
```

After pushing `tempObject` into `locations` array it will be like

```
locations = [
  { city: 'Los Angelas', zipcode: '90001', coordinates: 2321 },
  { city: 'New York', zipcode: '10001', coordinates: 3432 },
  { zipcode: '10000'}
];
```

Now when you will try to access `locations[2].city` or `locations[2].coordinates` then it will be `undefined`.